# What type of drivers do I write for a usb keypad?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have a [Razer Tartarus Classic keypad](https://support.razer.com/gaming-keyboards/razer-tartarus-classic/) from my old days of gaming on windows. I now want to get special functionality from it and learn things in the process. I'm well aware there are already drivers like openrazer and other software for this device coded in Linux. I wish to write my own drivers for the device purely the sake of learning.

The goal is to be able to remap keys to different functionalities and gain control of the built in lights on the device. The problem I have is I don't even know what type of driver I should write. Should I be writing a [character device driver](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html), a [usb driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/writing_usb_driver.html) or an [input device driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/input-programming.html)? Each of these information pages uses vastly different methods of communicating with the device and I'm not sure which one (if any) will do everything I need. Also any links to information related to the subject is very much appreciated.

Comment: A HID driver. But hey, where is the link to the specifications?

Comment: Added a link to the product page. Thanks for the response